# Selenium Webdriver : What would be the good practice to save url/link, in excel or properties file?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

In my test automation, I have these following links declared in a class:

1. link of the excel file
2. link of the chrome driver
3. link of the url of my app in test.
4. link of gmail (since I have the functionality to check email)
5. link of the extent-report html file.

All of these are being declared in one class. So, I just called it whenever i need to.

Now, I want to just store these links in an external file. **A:) Should I store these links in an excel file or B:) use Object Property instead?** Which is way handy to implement? What's more appropriate when it comes to this? I know it's really messy when you have the links being declared in a class. Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: Properties File would be a better choice if you are working with Java

Answer (score 3):

Create separate classes for the information.
Consider them to be similar to Page Objects.
Create one file that is used globally and then page or function specific ones that are included as needed.

This will lead you to centralize your data setup, ensure that you use the same values throughout the application and will encourage common name formatting and format for your setup data.

The classes *could* load text files, e.g. .csv but you may find it easier to just use specific classes to wrap them as directly available values scoped by their class.  This is an implementation detail.  I have used the same approach with different implementations of csv files, yaml files and directly in classes with methods.  A good approach here will depend on your individual situation.

Comment: hey michael, nice detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have not mentioned about environment you're using. Still I will answer:

- If you compare its not having big advantage of storing in excel.
- Currently I'm following practice to storing that link in .properties file
- I will suggest to use .properties file & its comparatively easy than excel